# Call ambigious due to a deleted function?

Tags: c++

In the code

```
void Fnc( long = 10 ) { }
void Fnc( ) = delete;

int main( int, char** )
{
  Fnc( );

  return 0;
}
```

At the Func call my compiler complains about an ambiguous call. Help! I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: Just because a function is officially deleted does not mean that it does not exist. It still participates in overload resolution, etc... Just that if the compiler winds up trying to invoke this function, you get a "oh no you didn't" error message.

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [*Delete Function Definition*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2326.html#delete):

> The definition form "=delete;" indicates that the function may not be
>   used. However, all lookup and overload resolution occurs before the
>   deleted definition is noted. That is, it is the definition that is
>   deleted, not the symbol; overloads that resolve to that definition are
>   ill-formed.

That's why you're getting ambiguous call.

Answer (score 4):

A deleted function is not removed, but tells the compiler that trying to call it is an error.

Your `Fnc();` could call either of the functions, and the compiler cannot tell which one you intended. That one of them is deleted doesn't matter until it is the single best match. Then it will be an error, not a hint to select some other function.